# Find analytically the sequence of iterations $x_n$ for Newton's method applied to the function $f(x) = x^2$ with the starting point $x_0 = 1$.

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Find analytically the sequence of iterations $x_n$ for Newton's method applied to the function $f(x) = x^2$ with the starting point $x_0 = 1$?

How would you do this, we can't use the recursive formula for Newton's method right? Thanks.

Comment: If you write the definition of Newton's method this problem basically solves itself.

Comment: Of course you can use that recursive formula - that formula _is_ Newton's method! For the given function, what _is_ $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $x_n$?

Comment: X[n+1] = X[n]- (X[n]^2/2X[n]), and then the use of the starting point ?. I thought that because they stated analytically, I would have to do something different.

Comment: @Shalid $\cdots = x_n-x_n/2 = x_n/2$. Now, if you compute a few terms, you oughtta spot a pattern fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks guys, managed to see the pattern